# Create list of elements which match a value

Tags: r, leaflet, dplyr

I have a table of values with the name, zipcode and opening date of recreational pot shops in WA state.

```
                             name   zip    opening
1                   The Stash Box 98002 2014-11-21
3                       Greenside 98198 2015-01-01
4                      Bud Nation 98106 2015-06-29
5       West Seattle Cannabis Co. 98168 2015-02-28
6                     Nimbin Farm 98168 2015-04-25
...
```

I'm analyzing this data to see if there are any correlations between drug usage and location and opening of recreational stores. For one of the visualizations I'm doing, I am organizing the data by number of shops per zipcode using the `group_by()` and `summarize()` functions in `dplyr`.

```
     zip count
    (int) (int)
1  98002     1
2  98106     1
3  98168     2
4  98198     1
...
```

This data is then plotted onto a leaflet map. Showing the relative number of shops in a zipcode using the radius of the circles to represent shops.

[image: Pot Shops in King County]

I would like to reorganize the `name` variable into a third column so that this can popup in my visualization when scrolling over each circle. Ideally, the data would look something like this:

```
     zip count                                    name
    (int) (int)                            (character)
1  98002     1                           The Stash Box
2  98106     1                              Bud Nation
3  98168     2  Nimbin Farm, West Seattle Cannabis Co.
4  98198     1                               Greenside
...
```

Where all shops in the same zipcode appear together in the third column together. I've tried various for loops and if statements but I'm sure there is a better way to do this and my R skills are just not up there yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the same `dplyr` command simply add a statement `paste(name,collapse = ",")`

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov probably `collapse = ", "` ?

Comment: Or `toString(name)` which is the same thing

Comment: Wow! People are amazing. Thank you so much. I knew it had to be simple.

Comment: @SeñorO, space in `collapse` is not needed, since `paste` default separator is a space

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov right! Was forgetting that the default `sep` is still added to `collapse` when supplied.